# cant find cbb backup path in couchbase for cbrestore tool

Tags: couchbase, couchbase-java-api

Hello everyone i am just starting to use couchbase and seem to have stuck while following the samples provided on the website specifically the one regarding couchbase community edition https://docs.couchbase.com/tutorials/index.html and while following this sample for java sdk i cant seem to find where does the path/to/cbb refer to in this default installation? Have i missed a step in this cause i have followed the sample up-till install and manage part and then jumped on to the development with java section because i am checking this out on a single node installation and not a cluster. Also while digging around the installation folders i have came across three samples but none of them refer to the movies bucket mentioned for restoring in the sample documentation. Need help

Comment: Which tutorial are you referring to? That link goes to the index, which lists a lot of tutorials.

Comment: @MatthewGroves this one https://docs.couchbase.com/tutorials/getting-started-ce/index.html